# Why may setAdapter() on my ListView produce a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm confused about this situation. The code below works fine, but Android Studio alerts me that setAdapter() may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException':

```
public class PlayerManagement extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Cursor c;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private String selectedPlayerId, selectedPlayerName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_management);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        try {
            MTGPS_DBHelper dbHelper = new MTGPS_DBHelper(this);
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            new getPlayersCursorAsync().execute();

            final SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(PlayerManagement.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c,
                                       new String[]{MTGPS_DB_Contract.Player.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME},
                                       new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

...
```

And this is the XML file activity_player_management:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_players_found"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As I say, everything works fine, but I don't get why Android Studio alerts me. If I declare the ListView as a class field, then the "problem" disappears. Only when I declare the Listview inside the onCreate method is when I get the alert.

Comment: You should declare your ListView globally in PlayerManagement Activity.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 it is not duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setAdapter() may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

That's just a warning. `findViewById()` returns `@Nullable` i.e. potentially `null` and you're calling a method on the return value without a nullity check.

You can suppress the warning e.g. by adding

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
```

on the previous line.

> If I declare the ListView as a class field, then the "problem" disappears. Only when I declare the Listview inside the onCreate method is when I get the alert.

The nullity analyzer cannot see where fields are written, and does not produce a warning. Analyses of local variables are easier.

Answer (score 0):

Change  `android:id="@android:id/list"` to  `android:id="@+id/list"`

`@+id`-This is used when you set your own id to a listView in the namespace of your application.

`@android:id`-This is used when you set id of a view to predefined android namespace.

Also replace `android.R.id.list` by `R.id.list`

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_players_found"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the activity declare them as follows:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class PlayerManagement extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Cursor c;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private String selectedPlayerId, selectedPlayerName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_management);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        try {
            MTGPS_DBHelper dbHelper = new MTGPS_DBHelper(this);
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            new getPlayersCursorAsync().execute();

            final SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(PlayerManagement.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c,
                                       new String[]{MTGPS_DB_Contract.Player.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME},
                                       new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        if(mAdapter!=null)
        {
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }   
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change listView id **`android:id="@android:id/list"`** to **`android:id="@+id/list"`**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```